# "syntax error at or near "ON"" when doing bulk manipulation using NHibernate + Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate

I'm trying to execute a parameterized "upsert" query using NHibernate named parameters but I'm getting an exception. The syntax appears to be correct but it is still throwing:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=could not execute native bulk manipulation query: ...
  InnerException:
       BaseMessage=syntax error at or near "ON"
       Code=42601
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       File=scan.l
       HResult=-2147467259
       InternalPosition=0
       Line=1053
       Message=42601: syntax error at or near "ON"
       MessageText=syntax error at or near "ON"
       Position=536
       Routine=scanner_yyerror
       Severity=ERROR
       Source=Npgsql
       SqlState=42601
       StackTrace:
            at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
            at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageWithPrepended(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode)
            at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpecting[T]()
            at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResultInternal()
            at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
            at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.Execute(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal()
            at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
            at NHibernate.Engine.Query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.PerformExecuteUpdate(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session)
       InnerException:
```

- If it helps, full exception here (moved to Gist due to long length and repeating content that's already below): https://gist.github.com/bherila/7ce76cbb3fb38ce12602d9ca91128b01

To my knowledge the syntax is correct according to PostgreSQL documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

### The query

```
insert into session (session_expiry,
    session_last_page,
    session_fbr_lh_state,
    session_user_id,
    session_user_guid,
    session_user_name,
    session_user_fname,
    session_image_url,
    session_user_balance,
    session_user_url_profile,
    session_user_cloud_name,
    session_last_qty,
    session_email,
    session_utm_source,
    session_utm_campaign,
    session_utm_medium,
    session_user_agent,
    session_guid) VALUES (
    :session_expiry,
    :session_last_page,
    :session_fbr_lh_state,
    :session_user_id,
    :session_user_guid,
    :session_user_name,
    :session_user_fname,
    :session_image_url,
    :session_user_balance,
    :session_user_url_profile,
    :session_user_cloud_name,
    :session_last_qty,
    :session_email,
    :session_utm_source,
    :session_utm_campaign,
    :session_utm_medium,
    :session_user_agent,
    :session_guid ) 
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET session_expiry = :session_expiry,
    session_last_page = :session_last_page,
    session_fbr_lh_state = :session_fbr_lh_state,
    session_user_id = :session_user_id,
    session_user_guid = :session_user_guid,
    session_user_name = :session_user_name,
    session_user_fname = :session_user_fname,
    session_image_url = :session_image_url,
    session_user_balance = :session_user_balance,
    session_user_url_profile = :session_user_url_profile,
    session_user_cloud_name = :session_user_cloud_name,
    session_last_qty = :session_last_qty,
    session_email = :session_email,
    session_utm_source = :session_utm_source,
    session_utm_campaign = :session_utm_campaign,
    session_utm_medium = :session_utm_medium,
    session_user_agent = :session_user_agent
```

### How I'm populating the parameters (in C#)

```
dbModel.CreateSQLQuery(SESSION_UPSERT)
    .SetParameter("session_guid", data.SessionId)
    .SetParameter("session_expiry", data.SessionExpiration)
    .SetParameter("session_last_page", data.SessionLastPage)
    .SetParameter("session_fbr_lh_state", data.SessionFbrLhState)
    .SetParameter("session_user_id", data.SessionUserId)
    .SetParameter("session_user_guid", data.SessionUserGuid)
    .SetParameter("session_user_name", data.SessionUserName)
    .SetParameter("session_user_fname", data.SessionUserFname)
    .SetParameter("session_image_url", data.SessionUserImageurl)
    .SetParameter("session_user_balance", data.SessionUserBalance)
    .SetParameter("session_user_url_profile", data.SessionUserUrlProfile)
    .SetParameter("session_user_cloud_name", data.SessionUserReferralCloudName)
    .SetParameter("session_last_qty", data.SessionLastQty)
    .SetParameter("session_email", data.SessionEmail)
    .SetParameter("session_utm_source", data.SessionUtmSource)
    .SetParameter("session_utm_campaign", data.SessionUtmCampaign)
    .SetParameter("session_utm_medium", data.SessionUtmMedium)
    .SetParameter("session_user_agent", data.SessionUserAgent)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. Had to update to PostgreSQL v9.5. Doh!